# cannot edit cell in datagrid WPF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I've a `DataGrid` in my view binded to an `ObservableCollection<>`. The binding works.

The problem is that I cannot edit any cell and don't understand why...

Here is my XAML :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ClientSpecifications, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Only this. Nothing more. But it doesn't work. I'm working with WPF, .NET4, EF.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article: [Overview of the editing features in the WPF DataGrid](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/10/01/overview-of-the-editing-features-in-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx)

The datagrid uses `IEditableCollectionView<T>` (which `ObservableCollection<T>` implements) - but in order for objects to be editable, you need to make sure that your object T has implemented the [`IEditableObject` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx). Once you do this, the Datagrid will recognize the collection items as editable and allow you to change them within the grid.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything :/
When I bind my collection on a listView, it works fine.

Comment: A listview is an entirely different control and doesn't require that interface, but also doesn't support Edit, Cancel Edit, Delete, Add, etc operations that a DataGrid supports. Can you post your implementation of the IEditableObject interface so I might see what's wrong?

Comment: it's ok, I changed it to a listView. I don't want the user to delete or add items.
But thanks a lot for your help. I will try it later (when I've more time).