# How to Set focus to inner element in a datagrid on cell click

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my DataGrid I have custom TextBoxes and ComboBoxes in each column. How shall I set focus to the control inside the cell when user single click on the cell?

Here is my code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>  
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column1">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox  x:Name="myCombobox" ItemsSource="{Binding UserTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedType}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: please format you code for better readability.

Comment: Take a look at this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033363/cannot-edit-cell-in-datagrid-wpf] and this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385950/cannot-edit-cells-of-my-datagrid-wpf-framework-4-5]

Comment: Check this weblog [WPF DataGrid: Tabbing from cell to cell does not set focus on control](https://iyalovoi.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/wpf-datagrid-tabbing-from-cell-to-cell-does-not-set-focus-on-control/)